# Firebase database not retrieving data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my first time using firebase and I have a few methods all contained in the same class that don't seam to be working as they should. nameExists always returns false, even when I can see in the console that the value stored at name is not null. userStatus is a DataSnapshot field in this class.

```
public Boolean nameExists(String name){
    if (getUserStatus(name) != null){
        return true;
    } else{ return false; }
}

 public String getUserStatus(String name){
    DatabaseReference tmpRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("userStatuses").child(name);
    ValueEventListener v = new statusesListener();
    tmpRef.addValueEventListener(v);
    tmpRef.removeEventListener(v);
        return userStatus;
}

 private class statusesListener implements ValueEventListener{

    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snap){
        userStatus = (String) snap.getValue();
    }
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error){
    }

}
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have overlooked the asynchronous nature of the `ValueEventListener` callbacks.  When a listener is added, it typically requires that the value be fetched from the Firebase server before it can be provided by the `onDataChange()` callback.  The callback fires asynchronously, usually many milliseconds after the listener has been added.

In your code, `getUserStatus()` adds the `statusesListener`, then removes it and returns `userStatus`.  All of that occurs before `onDataChage()` has fired, so the value of `userStatus` is unchanged.

Also, adding and immediately removing a `ValueEventListener` is not the typical use case and, given the listener's asynchronous nature, may cause it to never fire.  It is better to add the listener with [Query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/database/Query), which gives you the value one time and does not require the listener to be removed.

Comment: But I only need the data to be retrieved once,  my fear is that this will retrieve the data once the listener is added, then again when the value changes. If it takes several miliseconds for userStatus to be updated, how do do I know how long I will need to wait before trying to use the userStatus value, how do I implement this delay, and how do I verify that userStatus has actually been updated and the user hasn't just lost internet connection or some weird case. Also, why is this concept not in Google's Firebase guide?This seams like an important note to add,and a workaround should be given.

Comment: The listener added with `addListenerForSingleEvent()` only fires once, not for changes.  This is described in [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data) in the section titled Reading Data Once.  Regarding delays and waiting, your design must be event driven.  Assuming your code is running on the main (UI) thread, you can't block to wait for asynchronous responses.

Comment: Then how am I supposed to use retrieved data if I don't know when it's been retrieved?

Comment: Nevermind, I think I've solved this by using ASyncTask to wait for responses.